# how to make the newsletter checkbox checked by default in prestashop 1.7 in checkout process?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

How to make the newsletter checkbox checked by default in prestashop 1.7 in checkout process?

[image]

Update:
I found the file where the form is rendrered:
\modules\ps_emailsubscription\ps_emailsubscription.php

But amazing enough there are are no function defined to change attributes.

```
public function hookAdditionalCustomerFormFields($params)
{
    $label = $this->trans(
        'Sign up for our newsletter[1][2]%conditions%[/2]',
        array(
            '[1]' => '<br>',
            '[2]' => '<em>',
            '%conditions%' => Configuration::get('NW_CONDITIONS', $this->context->language->id),
            '[/2]' => '</em>',
        ),
        'Modules.Emailsubscription.Shop'
    );

    return array(
        (new FormField())
            ->setName('newsletter')
            ->setType('checkbox')
            ->setLabel($label));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct file that is rendering the form is:

/themes/[your-activated-theme]/templates/customer/_partials/customer_form.tpl

In the line 32 you can see this code that is the responsable to render the input fields of the form:

```
{block "form_fields"}
  {foreach from=$formFields item="field"}
    {block "form_field"}
      {form_field field=$field}
    {/block}
  {/foreach}
  {$hook_create_account_form nofilter}
{/block}
```

The new way to create form  fields is calling the smarty function "{form_field}", like the line 35.
This funciton is calling this file to create the different input's:

/themes/[your-activated-theme]/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl

So, my faster solution (I think that not is the best, but works) is to change directly in this file to say that make checked the checkbox input when it's the newsletter and optin input and it's in the authentication page:

Change this on line 91 in form-fileds.tpl file:

```
{if $field.value)}
```

To:

```
{if $field.value || ($field.name == "newsletter" && $page.page_name == 'authentication') || ($field.name == "optin" && $page.page_name == 'authentication')}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Hello the correct answer is not to forget "checkout too" to make all works well
Here the good code complete

```
{if $field.value || ($field.name == "newsletter" && $page.page_name == 'authentication') || ($field.name == "optin" && $page.page_name == 'authentication') || ($field.name == "newsletter" && $page.page_name == 'checkout') || ($field.name == "optin" && $page.page_name == 'checkout') }checked="checked"{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the previous answer didn't work, so I just changed the:

```html
{if $field.value}checked="checked"{/if}
```

to:

```html
checked="checked"
```

Regards, B